# Why image cannot be saved in database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I'm using VB.NET and SQL Server for my system. I have a problem saving an image into the database. I need to save and retrieve image on the same page but I get an error:

> unable to cast System.DBNull to system bytes.

I have tried several coding to fix my coding but it does not worked.

Code for retrieve image.

```vb
    Dim id As String = txtImages.Text.Trim() 'txtImages is textbox name
    Image1.Visible = id <> ""

    If id <> "" Then
        Dim dt As DataTable = GetData((Convert.ToString("SELECT ImagePic FROM masterlist WHERE id 
='") & Request.QueryString("id")) + "'") 'image data will be select depend on what user search in the 
serch textbox
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim bytes As Byte() = TryCast(dt.Rows(0)("ImagePic"), Byte())
            Dim base64String As String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
            Image1.ImageUrl = Convert.ToString("data:images/png;base64,") & base64String
        Else
            Image1.ImageUrl = ""
            Image1.AlternateText = "No image present in database with the name" 'if there is no image  
in db the message will displayed
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Code for save image

```
Dim fileName As String = String.Empty
Dim filePath As String = String.Empty
Dim getPath As String = String.Empty
Dim pathToStore As String = String.Empty
Dim bytes As [Byte]()
Dim fs As FileStreamenter code here
Dim br As BinaryReader
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Updateonlyimage_Sp3", cs) ' SQL command for this page is inside SQL Server I declare it as Insertapprovalcustom_Sp2"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

Try
    If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
        fileName = FileUpload1.FileName
        filePath = Server.MapPath("HSCODE/" & Convert.ToString(System.Guid.NewGuid()) & fileName) 
        'path to doucument inside approval_pdf file
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Request.QueryString("id"))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImagePicName", fileName)
        Dim getPos As Integer = filePath.LastIndexOf("\")
        Dim len As Integer = filePath.Length()
        getPath = filePath.Substring(getPos, len - getPos)
        pathToStore = getPath.Remove(0, 1)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImagePicPath", pathToStore)
        fs = New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        br = New BinaryReader(fs)
        bytes = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length))
        br.Close()
        fs.Close()
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImagePic", bytes)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType)
```

Comment: Tip: use parameters to pass the id to the query to retrieve the image - your current code is wide open for an SQL injection attack.

Comment: Are you getting the error when you try and save the image or when you try and retrieve it?

Comment: You need to step through your code line by line and confirm that each line is doing what you want it to do.

Comment: You should be able to tell us EXACTLY where in your code that is happening and EXACTLY what variable is `DBNull.Value`. The fact that you haven't indicates that you haven't actually investigated the issue for yourself, which means that you shouldn't have posted it at all. As already suggested, you need to debug your code first. If you had done that then you would likely be able to fix the issue for yourself but, even if you couldn't, you would be able to provide us with all the relevant information.

Comment: You also need to take note of the fact that SO expects a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code has a lot of stuff in there that is irrelevant to the issue, which makes it harder for us to identify the problem and also indicates that you haven't bothered to do any testing to isolate the issue yourself. It appears that you have struck some unexpected behaviour, thrown your hands up and done nothing but copy and paste your code here. Software development is much more than that. Debug first, then create a simple test project.

Comment: Are you sure your byte array has a value?  Have you checked that via debugging?  Next have a look at system.io.path. There are a few methods in there you might find helpful with parsing file names